# ClassNotFoundException: com.netflix.config.CachedDynamicIntProperty for SpringBoot 2 ribbon starter

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, netflix-ribbon

There is `SpringBoot 2.1.4.RELEASE` application with spring-cloud-starter-netflix-ribbon 2.1.1.RELEASE dependency.

Trying to run spring integration test (using `@SpringBootTest`) during test application startup such an exception is thrown: 
`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:com.netflix.config.CachedDynamicIntProperty`

Maven cloud dependencies used in project:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-ribbon</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Test property file:

`feign.hystrix.enabled=true
eureka.client.enabled=false
ribbon.eureka.enabled=false
some-my-mocked-service.ribbon.listOfServers=localhost:${mocked.port}`

Exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.netflix.loadbalancer.ILoadBalancer]: Factory method 'ribbonLoadBalancer' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lcom/netflix/config/CachedDynamicIntProperty;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:622)
```

Comment: Are you sure that this is really the complete stacktrace?

Comment: No, the initial stacktrace is much longer but I extract the main reason. Also this piece can be useful: `Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ribbonLoadBalancer' defined in org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.RibbonClientConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is ....//exception from question body

Comment: Ok, was just asking because sometimes it happens that people do not copy the root cause of the problem but some other parts of the stacktrace. That's more often the case the more autowiring is used :-)

Comment: Maybe you need the following dependency ```<dependency>
    <groupId>com.netflix.archaius</groupId>
    <artifactId>archaius-core</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: archaius-core didn't help(

Comment: Corrupt maven download is my guess

Comment: You could try to clean everything and make sure that the maven download was successfully (check your jar file in the maven repository). If that's surely not the problem the question is if you use the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` correctly to build your jar file? Could you edit your question and show the complete pom of yours? Because a `NoClassDefFoundError` means usually that something is wrong with your classpath.

Answer (score 1):

Run `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose` and check the tree for versions conflict - looks like **spring-cloud-starter-openfeign** and **spring-cloud-starter-netflix-ribbon** artifacts use different versions of **archaius-core**.